# Inputting data to stringstream with hexadecimal representation

Tags: c++, char, stringstream, crypto++, iomanip

I am attempting to extract a hash-digest in hexadecimal via a stringstream, but I cannot get it to work when iterating over data.

Using `std::hex` I can do this easily with normal integer literals, like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::stringstream my_stream;
my_stream << std::hex; 
my_stream << 100;

std::cout << my_stream.str() << std::endl; // Prints "64"
```

However when I try to push in data from a digest it just interprets the data as characters and pushes them into the stringstream. Here is the function:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <sha.h> // Crypto++ library required

std::string hash_string(const std::string& message) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    std::stringstream buffer;

    byte digest[SHA256::DIGESTSIZE]; // 32 bytes or 256 bits
    static SHA256 local_hash;

    local_hash.CalculateDigest(digest, reinterpret_cast<byte*>(
        const_cast<char*>(message.data())),
        message.length());

    // PROBLEMATIC PART
    buffer << std::hex; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SHA256::DIGESTSIZE; i++) {
        buffer << *(digest+i);
    }

    return buffer.str();
}
```

The type `byte` is just a typedef of `unsigned char` so I do not see why this would not input correctly. Printing the return value using `std::cout` gives the ASCI mess of normal character interpretation. Why does it work in the first case, and not in the second case?

Example:

```
std::string my_hash = hash_string("hello");
std::cout << hash << std::endl; // Prints: ",≥M║_░ú♫&Φ;*┼╣Γ₧←▬▲\▼ºB^s♦3bôïÿ$"
```

Comment: `>> std::hex >> data` maybe?

Comment: I have tried it but neither that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `std::hex` format modifier applies to integers, not to characters. Since you are trying to print `unsigned char`, the format modifier is not applied. You can fix this by casting to `int` instead. In your first example, it works because the literal `100` is interpreted as an integer. If you replace `100` with e.g. `static_cast<unsigned char>(100)`, you would no longer get the hexadecimal representation.

Second, `std::hex` is not enough, since you likely want to pad each character to a 2-digit hex value (i.e. `F` should be printed as `0F`). You can fix this by also applying the format modifiers `std::setfill('0')` and `std::setw(2)` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill), [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)).

Applying these modifications, your code would then look like this:

```
#include <iomanip>

...

    buffer << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SHA256::DIGESTSIZE; i++) {
        buffer << static_cast<int>(*(digest+i));
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much good sir!